# Why are my bitmap padding bytes out of sync when im positive it should be fine?

Tags: java, bitmap, padding

Im trying to print a hexadecimal string as binary bytes into a bitmap (in sequence)
for example:
   a6c832bac
   v
   1010
   v
   FFFFFF000000FFFFFF000000 (b,g,r) in pixel array.

the problem, i would assume, is with the "padding"
I can live with just printing this to the pixel array, but as you would expect, the image *should* be black/white, but theres a misalignment, and my image is multicolored...

I've tried searching around, and i've tried messing with the sequence. i'm new to java, so i dont know if there anything im missing. I really can't seem to figure out

This is the headers code, where i initialize the padding size, and after that is writing the header info to file, which i know is correct because all image viewers can load my bitmap.

```
int headers[] = new int[13];
        int WIDTH = (int)Math.sqrt(hexstring.length()*4) + 1;
        int HEIGHT = WIDTH;
        int extrabytes, paddedsize, offset;
        int bit = 0;
        extrabytes = 4 - ((WIDTH * 3) % 4);
        if(extrabytes == 4) extrabytes = 0;
        paddedsize = ((WIDTH * 3) + extrabytes) * HEIGHT;
```

This is the pixel array drawing code.

```
        int z = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (int yy = HEIGHT - 1; yy >= 0; yy--) {     // BMP PIXEL ARRAY, Bottom -> Top, Left -> Right
            for (int xx = 0; xx <= WIDTH - 1; xx++) {
                if(z < hexstring.length()){ // print valuable chars
                    String bit_string = String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(hexstring.charAt(z)), 16))).replace(" ", "0");
                    byte[] bits = bit_string.getBytes();
                    System.out.println("BIT STRING: " + bit_string);
                    for(int w = 0; w < 4; w++){
                    bit = (bits[w]-48)*0xFF;
                    System.out.println(bit);
                    outfile.write(bit);
                    outfile.write(bit);
                    outfile.write(bit);
                    }
                    z++;
                } else { //print eot
                    outfile.write(128);
                    outfile.write(128);
                    outfile.write(128);
                }
            }
            if (extrabytes != 0) {     
                for (int nnn = 1; nnn <= extrabytes; nnn++)
                {
                    System.out.println("PADDING");
                    outfile.write(0);   // can be any value
                }
            }
        }
```

I dont know how to include images, but i can provide my purposeful probing?

```
BIT STRING: 0110
0
255
255
0
BIT STRING: 1000
255
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 1000
255
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 1011
255
0
255
255
BIT STRING: 0011
0
0
255
255
BIT STRING: 1010
255
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 1111
255
255
255
255
BIT STRING: 1001
255
0
0
255
BIT STRING: 0011
0
0
255
255
BIT STRING: 1011
255
0
255
255
BIT STRING: 1110
255
255
255
0
BIT STRING: 0001
0
0
0
255
BIT STRING: 1010
255
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 1110
255
255
255
0
BIT STRING: 0100
0
255
0
0
BIT STRING: 0010
0
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 1110
255
255
255
0
BIT STRING: 0010
0
0
255
0
PADDING
PADDING
BIT STRING: 1000
255
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 1111
255
255
255
255
BIT STRING: 0100
0
255
0
0
BIT STRING: 0010
0
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 1111
255
255
255
255
BIT STRING: 0011
0
0
255
255
BIT STRING: 1100
255
255
0
0
BIT STRING: 0110
0
255
255
0
BIT STRING: 1101
255
255
0
255
BIT STRING: 1101
255
255
0
255
BIT STRING: 0001
0
0
0
255
BIT STRING: 1000
255
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 1101
255
255
0
255
BIT STRING: 0010
0
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 1000
255
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 0010
0
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 0111
0
255
255
255
BIT STRING: 1010
255
0
255
0
PADDING
PADDING
BIT STRING: 0010
0
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 0001
0
0
0
255
BIT STRING: 1010
255
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 1010
255
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 1010
255
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 0111
0
255
255
255
BIT STRING: 1000
255
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 0000
0
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 0110
0
255
255
0
BIT STRING: 0110
0
255
255
0
BIT STRING: 0110
0
255
255
0
BIT STRING: 1000
255
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 1111
255
255
255
255
BIT STRING: 0000
0
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 1010
255
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 0101
0
255
0
255
BIT STRING: 1110
255
255
255
0
BIT STRING: 0010
0
0
255
0
PADDING
PADDING
BIT STRING: 1010
255
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 1000
255
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 1100
255
255
0
0
BIT STRING: 0111
0
255
255
255
BIT STRING: 1100
255
255
0
0
BIT STRING: 1100
255
255
0
0
BIT STRING: 1010
255
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 0011
0
0
255
255
BIT STRING: 0101
0
255
0
255
BIT STRING: 0111
0
255
255
255
BIT STRING: 1110
255
255
255
0
BIT STRING: 0010
0
0
255
0
BIT STRING: 0000
0
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 1000
255
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 0001
0
0
0
255
BIT STRING: 1001
255
0
0
255
BIT STRING: 1000
255
0
0
0
BIT STRING: 0001
0
0
0
255
PADDING
PADDING
BIT STRING: 1111
255
255
255
255
BIT STRING: 0111
0
255
255
255
BIT STRING: 0001
0
0
0
255
BIT STRING: 0100
0
255
0
0
BIT STRING: 0001
0
0
0
255
BIT STRING: 0011
0
0
255
255
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
PADDING
EXTRA BYTES = 2
78 characters printed out of 78
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show the input, expected output, and actual output.  And please be explicit.

Comment: Unfortunately you don't show how you create the header. What I think is wrong is that you do not correctly set the offset to the bitmap image data (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header, offset 10 decimal)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was semi-complicated, but apparently the problem was in this.

````
for(int w = 0; w < 4; w++){
    bit = (bits[w]-48)*0xFF;
    System.out.println(bit);
    outfile.write(bit);
    outfile.write(bit);
    outfile.write(bit);
    }

    ```
    for some reason writing to the file in this loop just was unpredictable, and i ended up just converting my large hexadecimal string to a full binary string byte by byte
````